# Setting 'Connect' property of table drops primary key. Why?

Tags: ms-access, primary-key, connect

I am working on an 'accdb' application. Most of my tables are linked to SQL Server 2008. I want to give the user an option to connect to a different database, so I'm providing a screen that does the follows:

```
Private Sub cmdLinkTables_Click()
On Error GoTo cmdLinkTables_Click_Err
    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If InStr(1, tdf.name, "MSys") Then GoTo NextIteration 'skip system tables
        If Len(tdf.Connect) <= 0 Then GoTo NextIteration 'skip local tables
        tdf.Connect = Me.txtConnectionString
        tdf.RefreshLink
NextIteration:
    Next tdf
    Exit Sub
cmdLinkTables_Click_Err:
    MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical, GetAppTitle
End Sub
```

After connecting to a new database, everything worked fine, except for one table where the primary key was dropped for some reason, and thus it became uneditable (is that a word?). This is the new connection string I used:

```
ODBC;Description=***;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=SERVER2008\MSSQLSERVER2008;UID=***;PWD=***;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;DATABASE=***
```

And I thought that the problematic table is also necessary, so I'll provide the script created by SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblUsersPerm](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [User] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ScreenObjectName] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [ReadOnly] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Allow] [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I think this is all the necessary information, hope I'm right. Now, of course I can manually set a primary key and make the table editable again, but the user will not be able to do so.

Anyone has any idea what's the problem with the primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyone has any idea what's the problem with the primary key?

From what you've told us, the problem with the Primary Key is simply that it does not exist on the SQL Server table. I ran your DDL and it produced a table in my SQL Server database that had no PK. I went into the Table Designer and specified [ID] as the Primary key, saved my changes, and then did a `Script Table as > CREATE ...` and what I got was

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblUsersPerm](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [User] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ScreenObjectName] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [ReadOnly] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Allow] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblUsersPerm] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Thanks, I did mark 'ID' as identity, thought It was considered to be a PK, guess it's not the same. Anyway it works now